# Building XOR bruteforce python

Tags: python-3.x, binary, xor, brute-force

I solved a simple bruteforce XOR challenge using cyberchef.
Of course, I wanted more and build a script that do it.

The script should perform XOR test against a specific string.
I don't understand how to manipulate binary in python and this is my issue so far.

```
ciph = "q{vpln'bH_varHuebcrqxetrHOXEj"
    for decim in range(256):
        print(decim, ": ", ''.join([chr(ord(char) ^ decim) for char in ciph]))
```

Of course **'decim'** is not a bit so it's not working properly.
I have read stuff about bytearray but no sure how to handle it and if it's relevant here.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my bad, it is working well.

The flag is there but not at the same position as Cyberchief indicated because it performed a XOR bruteforce with Hexadecimal key.

Here I'm doing a XOR bruteforce with Decimal key, so yeah of course the flag is not at the same position ...